# Using queryset to 'filter' within form to display results from DB depending on option selected

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develop a view that has a list of records. Within that view is a 'filter' box I'd like to use so that when users select 'HK' or 'JP' as a location. It only displays records submitted for 'HK' or 'JP' depending on whats been selected > Submitted.

I have the layout working, but whenever I'm submitting a new 'filter' option, this returns all results no matter what.

Can anyone provide some insight? I suspect the problem lies in the views context, but I am just stuck.

views.py

```
def CLIENT_Overtime_Results(request):
    overtime_data = Overtime.objects.all()
    location = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OvertimeForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            location = form.data['location']
            overtimeid = Location.objects.all()
            #overtime_period = Overtime.objects.filter(
    else:
        form = OvertimeForm()
    template_name = "overtime/UBS_Overtime_Results.html"
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'location': location, 
        'overtime_data': overtime_data,
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Forms.py

```
class OvertimeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Location.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Overtime
        fields = ['location']

Filter button/options referenced in 'col-md-3'
```

HTML

```
    <div class="row">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-md-3">{{ form.location }}</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{% trans "Filter" %}</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right m-left-5" name="pdf">{% trans "PDF Report" %}</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" name="excel">{% trans "Excel Report" %}</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{% trans "ID" %}</th>
                <th>{% trans "Date" %}</th>
                {% if not location %}
                    <th>{% trans "Location" %}</th>
                {% endif %}
                <th>{% trans "Employee Name" %}</th>
                <th>{% trans "Client" %}</th>
                <th>{% trans "Hours" %}</th>
                <th>{% trans "Overtime Type" %}</th>
                <th>{% trans "Billable Type" %}</th>
                <th>{% trans "Approval" %}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for od in overtime_data %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ od.overtime_ID }} </td>
                <td>{{ od.overtimeDateStart }}</td>
                {% if not location %}
                    <td>{{ od.location }}</td>
                {% endif %}
                <td>{{ od.employee }}</td>
                <td>{{ od.client }} </td>
                <td>{{ od.hours }} </td>
                <td>{{ od.overtime_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ od.billable_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ od.approval|linebreaksbr }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% empty %}
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="9" class="text-center">{% trans "No overtime history." %}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is how the page looks right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUsAN.jpg

Comment: Well, you don't seem to have any code in the view that does any filtering if the form is valid.

Comment: I think its my mindset in this, I MAY have just found a solution, but I'll double check and get back to you.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you for jogging my mind. Included filter in the form.is_valid and that works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for future people coming to this page! As recommended by Daniel Roseman. I needed to include a filtering in the form.is_valid(): argument.

I added the following to my code:

```
overtime_data = Overtime.objects.filter(location=location)
```

This essentially filters and matches based on the updated location matching the location field in my model.

Updated code looks like this:

```
def CLIENT_Overtime_Results(request):
    overtime_data = Overtime.objects.all()
    location = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OvertimeForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            location = form.data['location']
            overtimeid = Location.objects.all()
            overtime_data = Overtime.objects.filter(location=location) #Added for filtering*
    else:
        form = OvertimeForm()
    template_name = "overtime/UBS_Overtime_Results.html"
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'location': location, 
        'overtime_data': overtime_data,
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```